# Generic Save vs Dedicated Update

Tags: java

I'm working on a application and I would like to know what you guys think it's the best practices.

I've a generic save function that saves a User if doesn't exist or updates if it exists.

Should I just call the save function every time I want to update the User or should I have dedicated functions.

For example, I want to lock the user should I have something like this:

```
private void lockUser(final long userId) {
    User user = userRepo.get(userId);
    user.setLocked(true);

    userRepo.save(user);
}
```

or

```
private void lockUser(final long userId) {
    userRepo.lockUser(userId);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's getting saved? To a file, to a database? Anytime you're using a locking mechanism, you should probably be working with try/except/finally. I think you're going to need to update this question to make it clearer what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the save method , probably you will have many tests before updating the LockFlag , for example you should test if it is an update of the username , code .... but the method LockUser will directly update the LockFlag of the user if exists , that's really implementaiton dependent but i prefer the second choice for a cleaner code .